# Find the solid of the volume restricted above to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and down to $z=b>0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Find the solid of the volume restricted above to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and down to $z=b>0$ .

---

I think in spherical coordinates system the volume is given by :$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{b}^{a}\rho^2\sin\left(\varphi\right)d \rho d \theta d\varphi$$

I also tried to use Cartesian coordinate system and I think the volume is :
$$\int_{-\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}^{\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}}\int_{-\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}-b^{2}}}^{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}-b^{2}}}\int_{b}^{\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}}}dzdydx$$

The only issue is that I'm not sure if the two integrals are the same, and if not then which one of them is correct and why the other one is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the question states the lower bound of $z$ as $z = b \gt 0$, it should also state that $b \lt a$ otherwise there is no volume bound.

The second integral is set up correctly but the first integral has mistakes -

- Lower bound of $\rho$ is not correct.
- Upper bound of $\phi$ is not correct.

The equation of the plane is $z = b$ which in spherical coordinates is,

$\displaystyle z = \rho \cos\phi = b \implies \rho = \frac{b}{\cos\phi} \ $ is the lower bound of $\rho$

Now for upper bound of $\phi$, at the intersection of the sphere $\rho = a$ and the plane, $\displaystyle \rho = \frac{b}{\cos\phi}$, $\cos \phi = \displaystyle \frac{b}{a} \implies \phi = \arccos \bigg(\frac{b}{a}\bigg) \ $ is the upper bound of $\phi$.

Comment: Think of a line segment of length $a$ from the origin making an angle $\phi$ with z-axis. First when $\phi = 0$, $z = a$ and line segment coincides with z-axis. Now as $\phi$ increases, $z$ decreases. When $\phi = \pi/2$, the line segment is horizontal (perpendicular to z-axis) and we then have $z = 0$. When $z = b$, the line segment is still making an angle $\lt \pi/2$ with z-axis.

Comment: No they do not all make the same angle. If you take the point on plane $z = b$ where $x = 0, y = 0$ (z-axis), clearly the $\phi = 0$ and radial distance from the origin to the plane is $b$ (given by $b / \cos\phi$). Now as you go farther from z-axis on the plane, $\phi$ increases and so does the radial distance. The max $\phi$ is at the intersection of the plane $z = b$ and the sphere (as we are not concerned with points on the plane that are outside the sphere). So max $\phi$ is $\arccos (b/a)$.

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates, the volume is
\begin{align}
\iint_{x^2+y^2<a^2-b^2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-x^{2}-y^{2}}-b\right)\> dxdy
=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \left(\sqrt{a^2-r^2}-b\right)\> rdr
\end{align}
and, in spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}\frac ba}\int_{\frac b{\cos \theta}}^a \rho^2\sin\theta \>drd\theta d\phi
=\frac{2\pi}3 \int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}\frac ba} \sin\theta \left( a^3-\frac{b^3}{\cos^3\theta}\right)\>d\theta
\end{align}
Both integrals evaluate to $\pi\left(\frac23a^3 -a^2b +\frac13b^3\right)$.